# Does a polynomial-like thing from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ always has coefficients in the rationals $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, functional-equations, rational-numbers

If $f(n) = a_k(n) n^k+\dots+a_1(n)n+a_0(n)$ is a function $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ with $a_1,\dots, a_k\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ does it follow that these functions $a_i$ are functions $\mathbb N\to \mathbb Q$, by which I mean that they just take rational values?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The way the question is posed is a little hard to read, but I think there's a real question in there whose answer is not obvious, at least to me.

Comment: @user275313 Perhaps because the OP asked what looks like a very similar question a few hours ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347861/can-every-polynomial-like-thing-with-coefficients-in-the-reals-be-written-as-a-p) (n.b. link requires 10k+ rep to see the deleted question), then deleted and reposted now, instead of clarifying the original question.

Comment: Answer to the question as stated is negative. Let $k=1$, let $a_1 \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary function, and define $a_0(n) = -n a_1(n)\,$. Then $f(n) = 0$ for $\forall n$.

Comment: If a polynomial only takes integer values over $\mathbb{N}$ then its coefficients are rational, but if the coefficients are functions of $n$ there is no reason for expecting that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the earlier one. Got it.

Comment: BTW, @dxiv, I don't know if it's intentional or sloppiness, but the question doesn't say how $a_0(n)$ is supposed to act on $\mathbb{N}$. If it's more restricted than the other $a_i$s your example might not be valid. I'm going to steal your idea and turn it into a more general counter example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'No'. Generalizing @dxiv's comment:

Let $g$ be an arbitrary function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and $a_0, a_1, ... a_{k-1}$ be arbitrary functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Define
$$ a_k(n) = \frac{ g(n) - a_0(n) - a_1(n)n .... - a_{k-1}(n)n^{k-1}}{n^k}$$

Then if you plug $a_0, a_1 ... a_k$ into your formula defining $f(n)$ you get $f$ is your arbitrary function $g$.

So no matter what your $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ function is, you can let your $\{a_i(n)\}_{i=0}^{k-1}$ be $\sin(n)$, $e^n$, or any other ugly transcendental functions, and you can still express your original function in the manner you asked.

(There is some complication with that definition of $a_k$ at $n = 0$, but so long as $g(0) = a_0(0)$ we can let the value of $a_k$ at $0$ be arbitrary and everything still works.)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessasarily. Let, $n=1$, and $a_1(1)=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_2(1)=-\sqrt{2}$, while, $a_i(1) \in \mathbb{N}$ for $i \neq 1,2$ and $a_i(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for $n \neq 1$ for simplicity. Then, still $f(1) \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just to be clearer to the OP, you should also say $a_i(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n \neq 1$.